# discord.js How to check if the bot has permissions from server/channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to check two things

1. Check if I have a specific SERVER permission for my bot (return true/false depending if it has that permission)
2. Check if I have a specific CHANNEL permission for my bot (return true/false depending on the value of the channel settings that has included my bot a specific permission. E.g I might have added my bot in the channel settings and set the "MANAGE SERVER" permission to true. How can I read that?)

Answer (score 6):

Found it!
To find the bot's permissions, let's say, after a message (msg =>) was sent by a user:

CHANNEL permission:

```
msg.guild.me.permissionsIn(msg.channel).has(<permission string here>)
```

SERVER permission

```
msg.guild.me.hasPermission(<permission string here>)
```

Answer (score 3):

for v14 you now have to use the `MemberManager` within `Guild` to access `me`

like so

```
msg.guild.members.me?.permissionsIn(message.channel).has(permissions);
```

Answer (score 2):

[LDinos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66123029/8289918) is correct for Discord.js v12. However, Discord.js v13 removed the `hasPermission` permission in favour of `permissions.has`.

Channel permissions:

```js
msg.guild.me.permissionsIn(msg.channel).has(permissions)
```

Guild (server) permissions:

```js
msg.guild.me.permissions.has(permissions)
```